# Google App Engine roll back previous update of a same version

Tags: google-app-engine

I tried deploying App Engine, but it updated the same version. The last update caused the working version to crash. Is it possible to restore to previous update of same version

I have used following command
appcfg.sh update [location]

Answer (score 1):

No, when you overwrite a version, the previous code for that version is permanently gone.

You should update your app.yaml file to a new version before deploying.

Comment: I have the original source code secure. This occured because two developers are working on this and when I updated existing version it changed the default. Now i receive "Error: NOT_FOUND" and url changes from http to https.

Comment: I have tried using the following command, is this the right way?
appcfg.sh -V [version_name]  update [repository_url]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by [repository_url]? You shouldn't be providing a url to the command, but a local file path. Have you looked at the examples online which show appcfg.sh deployment? At any rate, the original question has been answered - you will need to deploy a working version on top of the broken version to fix it. In future, be sure to deploy to a non-default version and then switch which version is default only when you're confident that the new version is fine in production.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the proper working code stored and you want to upload the same version I would suggest to do a `rollback` and then `update` the proper code again. 
If you are ok uploading a new version go directly with the `update`.

The proper use of the `rollback` or `update` command is :

1) Download the Java SDK from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/download) and extract it to a folder of your choice.

2) Open a command line and run this:

Windows

```
[path_of_java_sdk]\bin\appcfg.cmd update [project_path]\src\main\webapp\ -A [project_name] -V [version number]
```

Mac/Linux

```
./[path_of_java_sdk]/bin/appcfg.sh update [project_path]/src/main/webapp/ -A [project_name] -V [version number]
```

Example:

```
F:\user\folder\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.49\bin\appcfg.cmd update F:\myproject\somefolder\src\main\webapp\ -A AppName-1111 -V 3
```

If you want to perform a `rollback` simply replace the `update` on the above commands.

Comment: Thank you George.I tried deploying same way in linux and I get `Error: NOT_FOUND`. Also I'm getting URL changed from http to https

Comment: You are using java correct? Can you try deploying the app engine module via Android Studio?

Comment: I'm not completely sure how to do that. Only way of deployment I know is through appcfg

Comment: It seems to me that your issue lies in the directory structure (assuming command syntax is ok) , can you post step by step your exact deployment steps to see if there is an error there? Are you using the correct WAR location ?